# API Request - OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A

Tags: ruby, macos, ssl, heroku, homebrew

Another of of these questions, I know this question has been asked  (and answered) a lot on StackOverflow, but I can't get any of those to work for me and I also have a few questions I would like to learn.

Here is my error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A
```

To start, here is my system settings.

I am on OSX El Capitan version 10.11.6

```
openssl version
 OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

which openssl  
  /usr/bin/openssl

ruby -v 
  ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x86_64-darwin14.0]

rbenv -v
  rbenv 0.4.0
```

My questions are these:

1) Does this error mean that a certificate was sent back to me, and then my OpenSSL version was unable to verify it? Did the other server have a chance to read mine, or even see it yet? Is there a way to dig into this request using Net::HTTP and inspect this other than opening up a program like Wireshark? Once I call net::HTTP.new.request(request) I seem to lose control and it just errors.

2) Did I even successfully talk to the other server, and it denied me?

3) At what point in the request am I in when I get this message?

and most of all

4) What are my options to get past this point

- 4a. So far i'm seeing a possible brew solution, but I haven't been able to get brew to link
- 4b. I could manually install Mozilla's CA (Or any other CA) into my Mac OSX Keychain
- 4c. Can I attach the file using the request.ca_file = "file" as I tried in my code? (see below)
- 4d. Is there any other solutions  / best and most politically correct version?

5) Am I going to have this issue when I deploy to Heroku?

From what i'm reading, this is an issue of my OS not containing the correct CA files. the `ca_file` part is due to my first attempts to add the correct ca_file to my requests. I'm guessing I don't need that. I am using a Proxy with heroku because this API requires a static IP.

Here is my generic code

```
cert    = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'ssl', 'test_env', 'their_test_cert.der'))
ca_file = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'ssl', 'test_env', 'Class3PublicPrimaryCA.der'))

uri     = URI("https://xml.theirtestenv.com/api/receive")

headers              = {
  'x-IK-Version'       => 'IKR/V4.00',
}

proxy_host = "myproxyhose"
proxy_port = "1234"
proxy_user = "myproxyuser"
proxy_pass = "myproxypass"

proxy_request = Net::HTTP.new(uri.hostname, '443', proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_user, proxy_pass)

# http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(rsa_key)

proxy_request.use_ssl = true
proxy_request.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(cert)
proxy_request.ca_file = ca_file
proxy_request.verify_mode     = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
# proxy_request.ssl_version     = :SSLv3
# This doesn't seem to matter whether I put this or not...

# Tried variations of these...
# proxy_request.ssl_version = :TLSv1
# proxy_request.ciphers = ['DES-CBC3-SHA']

post_request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, headers)
post_request.content_type = "multipart/related"

response = proxy_request.request(post_request)
puts response.inspect
```

Also, i've noticed no matter what `proxy_requst.ssl_version` I put, my error always specifies SSLv2/v3, does that mean on their end they are requiring that version?

Sorry for all the questions. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll start answering some of these I have figured out as I go. 

"Also, i've noticed no matter what proxy_requst.ssl_version I put, my error always specifies SSLv2/v3, does that mean on their end they are requiring that version?"

If you look at `puts OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS`, the default SSL version is :ssl_version=>"SSLv23", so it is NOT them requiring it, it is specified in the defaults

Comment: Also, I have a little bit more information figured out, I'm thinking I don't need to worry about 4a. and 4b, since even though my Operating System and Ruby OpenSSL version don't match, the Ruby one will work fine for this purpose as far as I can tell.

4C. I have found I can manually add their ca_file, but I have changed it to use a cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new and then cert_store.add_cert.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile, but I just wanted to post that this was a couple of issues, the certificates I was passing were not the correct ones they were for the wrong environment. Once the correct certificates were passed this started working, though I never got the SSL Version questions quite figured out.