# Use Client Cert and TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA and other cipher suites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, net-http

I am working on an SSL Handshake with a server that requires TLSv1 and above.

They ciphers they support are:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

My current connection looks something like this:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("my.cer"))
http.ca_file = 'their_root.cer'
http.ciphers = ['need-to-figure-out']
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body = my_xml
response = http.request(request)
```

I need to figure out if Ruby supports these ciphers, since I can't find them in the listed ciphers using the `puts OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers` method, yet they are required in order to make this connection.

Also, does anyone know what I can change `http.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2` to, to make it also allow TLSv3?

### **EDIT:**

Thanks for all your comments. The cipher that works is

`proxy_request.ciphers = ["AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA"]`

And it shows up in Wireshark like

[image]

So thank you very much for that. I'm noticing that I am giving a client "Hello", but I never see a Server Hello in Wireshark, which coincides with the infamous error i'm getting

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A
 /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:927:in `connect'
```

Based on my wireshark, does anyone have any Idea what I am doing wrong?

You can see my script more fully in this question. Thanks in advance
[API Request - OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731735/api-request-opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-sta)

[image: wireshark]

Comment: I don't recall seeing a question on Ruby and client certs. Good luck with it. I've become so frustrated in doing simple Security 101 things in Ruby I no longer use it. Also see [How to set SSLContext options in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3818232) and [How to set TLS context options in Ruby (like OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22550213).

Comment: Reading the [ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html), `OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers` is the list of available ciphers.  This [mapping of openssl cipher suite names to rfc names](https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mappping.html) helped to narrow down what the name of each cipher is and they don't look to be supported.  [This documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.4.0/HTTPClient/SSLConfig:ssl_version) of ssl version doesn't show `TLSv1_3` as being supported.

Comment: @jww You might want to add this as an answer. It might not be fully complete but is better there than as a series of comments.

Comment: Thanks so much for all this info guys. Yes please post these as answers! I am parsing through this info and will keep you posted

Comment: Hey @jww your cipher was indeed correct. If you post that answer I would gladly accept. I am still having my issue of Read Server Hello A Issue, I posted Edit. If you add an answer i'll accept it and move my edit into a new issue, otherwise i'll continue it here. Let me know if anyone has any thoughts.. thanks again.

Comment: @cjxtr - OK, let me answer. We need a bigger discussion to explain what is going on in Wireshark, and how to confirm it. I suspect the server is sending an alert rather than its hello. Figuring out why the alert is sent will take some experimentation with `s_client`.

Comment: @jww Thank you for your response. This is a whole new world for me so I am still learning. I've been experimenting with s_client quite a bit now. I will open another question tomorrow, I realized I gave them an incorrect IP address, I had mistyped one number so I believe their firewall would have been denying me. Does that sound like why it would be sending the alert rather than its hello? They are not back in the office until Tomorrow, so I can't test wireshark with proper IP until after. I will post a new question tomorrow if that does not fix it, would love you to help me look at it!

Comment: @jww I posted a new question, would love to have a bigger discussion if you get the time! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924902/ruby-ssl-handshake-not-receiving-server-hello-back-using-proxy-nethttp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They ciphers they support are:
>
> ```
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> ```

And:

> ```
> http.ciphers = ['need-to-figure-out']
> ```

You can map the [IANA cipher suite names](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4) like `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`, to  [OpenSSL cipher string names](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html), like `AES128-SHA`, using the [`openssl ciphers` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html). Its a simple lookup - just search the page for the IANA registry name and you will land on OpenSSL's name eventually.

I believe the cipher string you should use is:

```
http.ciphers = ["AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA"]
```

---

> ... does anyone know what I can change `http.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2` ...  to make it also allow TLSv3?

For this in OpenSSL, you need to set context options. In Ruby, you need to set `OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2` through`OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1`. That will leave TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 (when TLS 1.3 becomes available). Also see [How to set TLS context options in Ruby (like OpenSSL::SSL::SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22550213).

The `TLS_RSA_WITH_*` schemes are RSA key transport schemes. TLS 1.3 will not offer them. They have been removed in favor of schemes that provide forward secrecy. Schemes that provide forward secrecy are the Diffie-Hellman ones, like `TLS_DHE_*` and `TLS_ECDHE_*`.

Even the banking industry could not get the [IETF to change the decision](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg21275.html). Hat's off to the IETF for holding their ground. I think they are a bit too accommodating at times and that often leads to weaker security. But I think they made the right decision in the post-Snowed era, where we have a good idea of the extent of the snooping and spying.

Answer (score 0):

Following @jww answer, there is a ruby library allowing you to map OpenSSL cipher names with IANA / standard / RFC names:

```rb
require 'tls_map' # gem install tls-map

tm = TLSmap::App.new


tm.search(:openssl, 'AES128-SHA', :iana)
# => {:iana=>"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"}
```